# R: passing argument name in dots (...) through a third string variable

Tags: r, function

Imagine you have a simple function that specifies which statistical tests to run for each variable. Its syntax, simplified for the purposes of this question is as follows:

```
test <- function(...) {
  x <- list(...)
  return(x)
}
```

which takes argument pairs such as `Gender = 'Tukey'`, and intends to pass its result to other functions down the line. The output of `test()` is as follows:

```
test(Gender = 'Tukey')
# $Gender
# [1] "Tukey"
```

What is desired is the ability to replace the literal `Gender` by a dynamically assigned variable `varname` (e.g., for looping purposes). Currently what happens is:

```
varname <- 'Gender'
test(varname = 'Tukey')
# $varname
# [1] "Tukey"
```

but what is desired is this:

```
varname <- 'Gender'
test(varname = 'Tukey')
# $Gender
# [1] "Tukey"
```

I tried tinkering with functions such as `eval()` and `parse()`, but to no avail. In practice, I resolved the issue by simply renaming the resulting list, but it is an ugly solution and I am sure there is an elegant R way to achieve it. Thank in advance for the educational value of your answer.

NB: This question occurred to me while trying to program a custom function which uses `mcp()` from the `effects` package in its internals. The said `mcp()` function is the real world counterpart of `test()`.

EDIT1: Perhaps it needs to be clarified that (for educational purposes) changing `test()` is not an option. The question is about how to *pass* the tricky argument to `test()`. If you take a look at NB, it becomes clear why: the real world counterpart of `test()`, namely `mcp()`, comes with a package. And while it is possible to create a modified copy of it, I am really curious whether there exists a simple solution in somehow 'converting' the dynamically assigned variable to a literal in the context of dot-arguments.

Comment: are you just trying to make sure the named arguments are not passed to the wrong functions?

Comment: Hi @rawr. No, not really. I'm trying to program with `mcp()`, see NB. I need to supply dynamic input for `mcp()` which operates like my `test()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this:

```
varname <- "Gender"
args <- list()
args[[varname]] <- "Tukey"
do.call(test, args)
```

Comment: Indeed, that processes arguments as intended. I was hoping to learn about some obscure function here, but `do.call()` can definitely be used. Thanks!

Comment: It's more often the cleanest solution, and saves resorting to NSE, which can be very messy and unintuitive (and thus difficult to maintain/debug).

Answer (score 2):

This works:

```
test <- function(...) {
  x = list(...)
  names(x) <- sapply(names(x), 
                     function(p) eval(as.symbol(p)))
  return(x)
}

apple = "orange"
test(apple = 5)
```

Comment: Thanks @Jordi, though modifying the function itself is not feasible, see other comments as to why.

Answer (score 2):

We can use

```
test <- function(...) {
  x <- list(...)
  if(exists(names(x))) names(x) <- get(names(x))
  x

} 



test(Gender = 'Tukey')
#$Gender
#[1] "Tukey"

test(varname = 'Tukey')
#$Gender
#[1] "Tukey"
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun. Modifying `test()` is something I would like to avoid (see NB and EDIT1 for reasons). But yeah, otherwise it is a working solution.